# Spring, Angular JS and exception handling in the service layer

Tags: java, angularjs, json, ajax, spring-mvc

Our development team is building an application that uses [jasper-reports](/questions/tagged/jasper-reports) 6.2.0, [spring-mvc](/questions/tagged/spring-mvc) 3.2.14, [java-ee-7](/questions/tagged/java-ee-7), [tomcat](/questions/tagged/tomcat) 8 and in the front-end we use [angularjs](/questions/tagged/angularjs). Our [rest](/questions/tagged/rest) requisitions are all made via [ajax](/questions/tagged/ajax).

The application is entirely built to receive [json](/questions/tagged/json) objects as response for our requisitions, because our requisitions via [angularjs](/questions/tagged/angularjs) are all made via Ajax. In a specific application feature we have a regular get requisition using `window.location = url`, because we need to return a streaming which is nothing more than a byte array containing a PDF file content.

That being said, when we have a back-end error while generating this PDF file our application redirects user to a blank screen with a [json](/questions/tagged/json) object printed in it.

I've already had experience in [spring-mvc](/questions/tagged/spring-mvc) exception handling globally ou per exception case, using exception handling with [ExceptionHandler](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ExceptionHandler.html) annotation or per [ControllerAdvice](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ControllerAdvice.html) to generalize the exception handling, but always handling classes in the controller layer annotated with [Controller](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/Controller.html) returning a [ModelAndView](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/ModelAndView.html) object, but never classes in the service layer annotated with [Service](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/stereotype/Service.html).

My question is how to capture a exception and make the application redirects users to a error screen with some parameterized message when we have regular get requisitions.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, and even if it's not exactly an answer to the question, main issue is not server side but client side :

stop doing `window.location = url` to download Content-Disposition:attachement files in an RIA application. Particularly when the download can cause errors thrown to the client. really.

Libs like fileDownload ( https://github.com/johnculviner/jquery.fileDownload ) allow to download the file in background, avoiding all the mess when an error append, and the UI freeze waiting for the server response.

Comment: I've already used this in another application. I'll try yout approach again.

Answer (score 0):

So lets say you want to take care of exception on client side on the basis of http status code then you can make a interceptor like :

```
var app = angular.module('appname',[]);

app.factory('myHandler', function ($injector) {
    var interceptor = {
        response: function (response) {
            .
            .
            .
            return response;
        },
        responseError: function (response) {

            if (response.status == 401) {   
                location.href = "#/error";   
            }

           else if(response.status == 403){...}

           else if().....

            return response;
        }
    };
    return interceptor;
});
```

and inject it in your application as :

```
    app.config(function ( $injector) {    
        $httpProvider.interceptors.push('myHandler');
        ...
     });
```

now every request would first go here , check if error status or whatever you want it to and then if no error (in which case you dont change location.href) it continues ,magically to wherever it was going else goes to specified templateURL on the basis of routeProvider.

Helpful links [injector](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$injector), [httpProvider](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$httpProvider)

Comment: I'll try to do this as you said, but this is my first experience with angular, so maybe I'll try the other answer approach as well if this consumes me much time, but thanks for the answer.

Comment: Do you understand portuguese? I got a particularlly good answer in portuguese stack overflow.